Run basic UI test Xamarin UITest, System.Net.Http.HttpIOException
I am trying to run basic test by Xamarin.UITest:
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using Xamarin.UITest;

namespace ProjectUITest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        IApp _app;

        [SetUp]
        public virtual void BeforeEachTest()
        {
            _app = ConfigureApp
                .Android
                .ApkFile("C:/xxx/bin/Debug/net8.0-android/xxx.apk")
                .StartApp();
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
        }
    }
}

And there is an issue:
 Test1
   Source: UnitTest1.cs line 22
   Duration: 11,2 sec

  Message: 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : An error occurred while sending the request.
  ----> System.Net.Http.HttpIOException : The response ended prematurely. (ResponseEnded)

  Stack Trace: 
HttpClient.SendData(String endpoint, String method, HttpContent content, ExceptionPolicy exceptionPolicy, Nullable`1 timeOut)
HttpClient.Post(String endpoint, String arguments, ExceptionPolicy exceptionPolicy, Nullable`1 timeOut)
HttpApplicationStarter.Execute(String intentJson)
AndroidAppLifeCycle.LaunchApp(String appPackageName, ApkFile testServerApkFile, Int32 testServerPort)
AndroidAppLifeCycle.LaunchApp(ApkFile appApkFile, ApkFile testServerApkFile, Int32 testServerPort)
AndroidApp.ctor(IAndroidAppConfiguration appConfiguration, IExecutor executor)
AndroidApp.ctor(IAndroidAppConfiguration appConfiguration)
AndroidAppConfigurator.StartApp(AppDataMode appDataMode)
Tests.BeforeEachTest() line 15
RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithNoArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
--HttpIOException
HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

The Android Emulator is trying to run this test, the screen changes but after short time the issue appears. I suppose there is some problem with Android Emulator. Also I unchecked "Fast deploment" in the tested project properties.
Test project settings:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.14.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SharpZipLib" Version="1.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.UITest" Version="4.3.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="NUnit.Framework" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

